# Foreach loop undefined index

Tags: php, html, if-statement, checkbox, foreach

I am writing a code where I've made HTML checkboxes and then use php script (checkform.php) to produce a foreach loop listing what items were selected. I can't get the loop to work no matter what I do, and I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've tried pre-defining the array or creating an empty one for the values to go into which also does not work. I Need help please!

```html
<form action="checkform.php" method="post">
          <p><fieldset><legend>Register Your Interests</legend>
<!-- checkbox input to select options -->
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="Gauge" value="Gauge"> Gauge </label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="thermometer" value="thermometer"> Thermometer </label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="wind" value="wind"> Wind</label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="lightning" value="lightning">Lightning</label>
            <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="hygro" value="hygro"> Hygro </label><br>
```

```html
if(!empty($_POST["interests"]))
  {
    echo "You have chosen the following workshops:";
    foreach($_POST["interests"] as $checked)
    {
      echo "<p>" . $checked ."</p>"
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo"You have not chosen a workshop, but we add new workshops all the time. We'll keep you updated by e-mail.";
  }
```

Comment: When you say "I can't get the loop to work," what do you mean? Does the PHP code even run? Is there an error message?

Comment: sorry to be more specific, when i run the code and select various checkboxes, it gives me the else statement "you have not chosen a workshop....". I'll also get an error code stating "Undefined index: interests in C:\wamp64\www\checkform.php" and "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " . I;m not sure what is going wrong

Comment: It looks like your `interests` data isn't being passed via post to PHP. You could debug if it's setup or you could add `print_r($_POST)` to see if you've received anything at all.

Comment: I realized that when I was reloading the program to see how my adjustments in the script worked in the browser, that it wasn't actually updating. I was able to solve this issue though, but I really appreciate your help!